# Given that the integer solutions of the inequality $0≤ax+5≤4$ for $x$ are $1,2,3,4$. Find the range of the constant $a$.

Tags: inequality

> Given that the integer solutions of the inequality $0≤ax+5≤4$ for $x$ are $1,2,3,4$. Find the range of the constant $a$.

**My solution:** As the $x$'s are positive, we can write
$$-5/x≤ a ≤-1/x.$$
Now taking $x$ as $1,2,3,4$ we get $a∈ [-5/4,-1/4]$.

Please tell if I am correct, it will be a great help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that :
$$0\le ax+5\le 4$$
$$-5\le ax\le -1$$
$$-\frac{5}{x}\le a\le -\frac{1}{x}$$

For $x=1$ : $$-5\le a\le -1$$
For $x=2$ : $$-\frac{5}{2}\le a\le -\frac{1}{2}$$
For $x=3$ : $$-\frac{5}{3}\le a\le -\frac{1}{3}$$
For $x=4$ : $$-\frac{5}{4}\le a\le -\frac{1}{4}$$

Now, find the place where the range of $a$ for all $x$ is intersect. From inspection, the place where all four of $x$ is intersect is :
$$-\frac{5}{4}\le a\le -1$$

Here is the references image for better visualisation. The red part is the place where its intersect for all $x$.
[image]

Comment: I do appreciate if you can accept my answer as the best answer. Thank you.